# OverflowError: out of range integral type conversion attempted in iota_client Python library

Tags: transaction, python, client-library

I am trying to send a list data to IOTA Ledger as follow

client = iota_client.Client()

message_temperature = client.message(
index="Pasteur1_Tempdata", data=temp_list
)

where my temp_list is [725, 702, 746, 734, 715, 722, 706, 746, 737, 714, 741, 732, 715, 726, 704, 749, 734, 715, 722, 706, 746, 737, 714, 741, 732, 715, 715, 722, 706, 746, 737, 714, 741, 732, 715, 726, 704, 749, 734]

which gives overflowerror as mentioned in subject. But it manage to send two digit integer list.

What is the limitation here is iota_client library do not support conversion of large integers?

Comment: What's your data type of `temp_list`?
You'd need to convert to bytes and send it. `.encode("utf8")`

Comment: Thank You for responding. temp_list is type list[int]. Actually I want to send float values like 72.5, 70.2 etc. (diving 725/10 after receiving) I am trying to understand here that I am able to send two digit integer without encoding what is the reason behind that it won't take 3 digit integer. 

As you suggested I will try converting it to bytes first.

Comment: It'll work any number of digits. You need to encode the entire thing. The way it's coming, the message will treat each object in array as separate entity. Hence would fail for numbers greater than 255.

Comment: Thank you. it worked. Here is the code I used


*****encoding*******
client = iota_client.Client()
data = [72.5, 70.3, 69.5, 55.2, 45.6, 89.6, 42.2]
# encoding utf string into list of bytes
data_str = str(data).encode('utf-8')
message = client.message(
    index="some_data_index", data=data_str

*******Decoding*****
client = iota_client.Client()

message = client.get_message_data("your message id")
data = message['payload']['indexation'][0]['data']
data_bytes = bytes(data)
decoded_str = data_bytes.decode('utf-8')

Comment: Perfect. Could you also add that as an answer so it might help others?

Answer (score 0):

From [K.Baig's comment](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/overflowerror-out-of-range-integral-type-conversion-attempted-in-iota-client-py#comment3902_2898):

Thank you. it worked. Here is the code I used

**Encoding**

```
client = iota_client.Client()

data = [72.5, 70.3, 69.5, 55.2, 45.6, 89.6, 42.2]

# encoding utf string into list of bytes
data_str = str(data).encode('utf-8')
message = client.message(index="some_data_index", data=data_str)
```

**Decoding**

```
client = iota_client.Client()

message = client.get_message_data("your message id")

data = message['payload']['indexation'][0]['data']
data_bytes = bytes(data)

decoded_str = data_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```